# Using instance variable Linkedlist() in method - why do I have to make new in method body

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, queue, instance-variables

this is my first post here. I have recently started to get interested in learning Java, I have read through some beginner level tutorials, kept http://docs.oracle.com as my bookmark and read several sample codes.

Now messing with my own for practice I discovered something weird for which I couldn't  find any satisfying answer in manuals/tutorials/documentation.

Theres a little class I produced to practice IO, and queue style objects. It is meant to create an object containing file name, and an empty linkedlist. Then it has a method for that given file to be read and lines from that added one by one to the linkedlist queue.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.util.LinkedList;


    public class Handle
    {
    public File filehandle;
    public LinkedList<String> queue;

    Handle (File filename)
        {
        filehandle=filename;
        LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();    
        }

    public void addq()
        {
        try{
            FileReader ava;
            ava = new FileReader(filehandle);
//without initializing new linekedlist queue it'll give NPE in queue.add
//why can't it use class/instance variable queue it does fine with filehandle
            queue = new LinkedList<String>();
                BufferedReader br = null;
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(ava);
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                queue.add(sCurrentLine);
                }
            queue.offer("POISON");
            }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
```

The weird thing - When tried to use class variable/instance variable queue (public LinkedList queue) declared in class, the one also initiated  in constructor, inside the method, it compiled fine but at the runtime it threw NPE at queue.add lines. NPE faded as I initialized method variable queue inside method. Why can't the method add to class variable queue? It seems to use the fielhandle variable just fine!
Also as shown by the poll method result in code running the class(posting it down) - it still seems to actually add the lines into the instance variable queue not just temporary method variable. (Which is of course good but I do not understand how and why)
Down here is the code that I used to run the Handle class in.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    class Runner
    {

      public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        File file = new File("proovidest.csv");
        Handle handle =new Handle(file);
//using the constructor, now we have object with filehandle and empty queue variables
        handle.addq();
        String mison;
//so apparently the instance variable queue is still filled with lines (good) 
//but how? the method had to delcare its own variable (why), but still the class field is //now filled? how?
        while ((mison = handle.queue.poll()) != "POISON")
        {System.out.println(mison);}

        }
    }
```

So can anybody give me good explanation why I couldn't acess the class variable queue in method in runtime, although I was able to use filehandle variable. 
What SHOULD I do to access it then?
Can anybody tell me how the class field queue then still got filled, although I declared a new variable inside the method. Or does the  handle.queue.poll somehow detect variables form methods?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
Handle (File filename) {
  filehandle=filename;
  LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();    
}
```

You don't initialize the instance field `queue`, rather you create a new local variable with the same name, which is valid only in the constructor. Change it to:

```
Handle (File filename) {
  filehandle=filename;
  queue = new LinkedList<String>();    
}
```

and it should not throw a NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your constructor, you declared a local variable queue, hiding your class variable!

```
Handle (File filename)
        {
        filehandle=filename;
        this.queue = new LinkedList<String>();    
        }
```

Comment: Aha so this.queue = new LinkedList<String>(); or queue = new LinkedList<String>(); should create new queue when firing up the constructor, jet not hide class variable. But as I have LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>(); would declare a new variable? So the type declaration before variable name is the one that turns it from initialization/filling with new value etc. to the declaration of new varaible alltogether?

Comment: Yes, it's just like that: in your example code, you declare a local variable (by prefixing it with a type declaration) which goes away when the constructor finishes.BTW: you should never declare instance variables in your class as "public", make them protected or private - they are internals of your class and should not be mutilated from outside.

Comment: In a way I would like this queue to be acessible for outside classes. The long term planning was something like this - create a class that opens a file and starts stuffing a queue line by line. Now other classes can jump in maybe even many of them in different threads etc. and start "slurping" lines out from queue. If not making a public queue inside this class how would you accomplice this kind of tasks? The idea is to develop this to be a "pump" kind of piece for a pipeline that reads lines from files and feeds them downwards, the latter pipe and filter etc. parts then being interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the visibility of your `LinkedList`. It is only visible in your private constructor. To use the queue `LinkedList` just write this in your constructor:

```
queue = new LinkedList<String>();
```

furthermore remove that in `addq`:

```
queue = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Comment: Aha so this.queue = new LinkedList<String>(); or queue = new LinkedList<String>(); should create new queue object when firing up the constructor, jet not hide class variable.\nBut as I have LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>(); would declare a new variable? So the type declaration before variable name is the one that turns it from initialization/filling with new value etc. to the declaration of new varaible alltogether?

Answer (score 0):

Looks there is no place to fire NPE on your code. 
It will fire File not found exception if mention file not in location.

Can you post stack trace to more investigations.